# Regex from Begining Pattern (Inclusive) to Next Beginning Pattern (Exclusive)

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I'd like to think I'm pretty good at RegEx, but this one has me stumped. Search string looks like this...

```
ISA*lots**of~other~data**with~~no terminating **pattern~ISA*lots**of~other~data**with~~no terminating **pattern~ISA*lots**of~other~data**with~~no terminating **pattern~ISA*lots**of~other~data**with~~no terminating **pattern~
```

- No line breaks.
- `ISA*` is a consistent starting pattern.
- The rest of the string is completely unpredictable.
- I need `ISA*` and all characters until the next instance of that pattern.

#### What I've Tried

A positive look-ahead, but this doesn't capture the last result.
`(ISA\*(.*(?=ISA\*))?)`

A positive look-behind, but I can't figure out how to make it lazy. If it's not lazy, there is only one match. But if it is lazy, you get the right number of matches, but only one additional character after the pattern.
`ISA\*(?<=ISA\*).*?`

The other solution is to programmatically `split` or `explode` the string, remove the first (empty) result, and then re-attach the delimiter to each result. Indeed, that is what I already have in place. But the size of the file, the large number of results, and the post-processing causing performance issues. In a preliminary test, using regex appears to offer some worthy performance gains.

---

This is being processed with PHP. The string is sourced from an AS400 system, in an "EDI Transaction" text file. I have yet to find any libraries that contain a working regex for this type of file.

Comment: try [`$res = preg_split('/\b(?!^)(?=ISA\*)/', $str);`](https://eval.in/801917)

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks for your response. You should submit this as an answer. It accomplishes the task in the fewest lines of code.

Comment: Restored my answer. Glad it's of help for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$res = preg_split('/\b(?!^)(?=ISA\*)/', $str);
```

- `\b(?!^)` split at any [*word boundary*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) but not at start
- `(?=ISA\*)` [if followed](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) by the specified substring

[See php demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/801917) or [regex demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/h24vTF/2)

If `~` before `ISA` is predictable, use [`(?<=~)` instead of `\b(?!^)`](https://regex101.com/r/h24vTF/1).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following lookahead based regex:

```
ISA\*(.*?)(?=ISA\*|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9faSeb/1)

**Details**:

- `ISA\*` - a literal `ISA*` substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible (due to the lazy `*?` quantifier) up to (but excluding from the match)...
- `(?=ISA\*|$)` - either `ISA*` or end of string (since it is a lookahead, the text matched with the pattern is not put into the returned match value).

Another variation of the same regex is

```
ISA\*((?:(?!ISA\*).)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9faSeb/2). Unrolled version (the most efficient):

```
ISA\*([^I]*(?:I(?!SA\*)[^I]*)*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9faSeb/3).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try expressing what to capture instead:

```
ISA\*(?:[^I]|I[^S]|IS[^A]|ISA[^*])+
```

using `preg_match_all`